# multisite detect subsite blog number

Tags: multisite

We have a multisite installation of Wordpress where we show events from subsites on the main blog.

for the detailed event pages which are shown on the main blog we would like to detect from which blog they coming from.

We need to execute a switch_blog($numberblog) where $numberblog is the ID of the blog who owns the event.

Could not find a function which does this, anyone able to help out?

Comment: It might useful to give a little extra detail, like an example of the type of event you are tracking.  Are these real-life events, like Events Manager Pro uses, or are these code-level events, like a user logged in?

Comment: You're right will add more specific info next time. In this case it was an event from Events Manager Pro, where we found the answer. These events have a blog id attached to it which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the plugin we used for the events (Events Manager Pro) had an extra metadata field for each event which contained the blog id so this problem is solved